# AnyLogic - inheritance of properties in batch block

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I want to store process times in my model for each agent of type `Box`. For this purpose I have created a Java class `ProcessData`.
My problem is that I always get NullPointerExceptions. I don't know if it's because of my code or the functionality of the batch block.

[image]

When the wait block reaches a certain size, all agents of type `Box` are routed to the batch block. The `batch agent` then waits in the seize block for staff member. If the agent is then seized, each agent of type Box contained in the batch agent should then get a start processing time. This is my code at enter of the delay block: `box.getProcessData().add(new ProcessData(date(), duration()));`. Using a constructor, I add the start time and duration as new variables to a new ProcessData entry.

To determine the end time of each Box agent I have the following code at unbatch block entry: `box.getProcessData().getLast().setEnd(date());`

Since I have a NullPointerException I can't tell exactly where it came from. My guess is that I have a bug with addressing the code: should I use `agent.` (from batch) or `box.` (name of original agent before batch)? Or is it not possible to give the batch agent properties that are inherited by the box agent?

First error is at unbatch, so the second code from above and second error is the following `public void onExit( Box batch, Box agent ) { _unbatch_onExit_xjal( this, batch, agent ); }`.

Following the screenshot of my error: [image]

Comment: NullPointers always yield a blue link to the actual line of code causing it. Pls share a screen of the error and a screen of where it is pointing. This likely will also help you fix it yourself.

Comment: re box or agent: learn about the magic lightbulb here: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling it explains what these terms are and how to use them

Comment: I didn't include a screenshot because it directs me to my second code (from above) without any further information. I know smth's wrong with my code but I have no clue what could be wrong. 
And also there's no lightbulb in any of the boxes I put my code in...

Comment: What does the NPE actually say? Please always share screenshots of errors, they gives clues you may not know about yet ;)

Comment: Okay I edited my post Ben :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have with this model first,is that you are seizing a resource for the batch without releasing that resource... you need to release before unbatch

your error nevertheless is related to some code that you wrote in the on exit action of the unbatch block that you are unfortunately not telling us

But to discover what is null, check with a traceln() the value of the variables that are present in the on exit section of the unbatch in order to print on the screen what is null

Comment: Ok thanks for the input Felipe! Do you know how it looks like when I set a variable to the batch agent, if then all included agents box also get assigned the same variable?

Comment: on batch action you can do batch.variable=agent.variable

Comment: after the batch block you access the batched agents using agent.contents() this will return a list of all the agents that were batched